# wpdb->query prepare doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I followed the introduction to use prepare to insert some data to the table.

The code is like this:

```
$wpdb->query(
     $wpdb->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos VALUES
            (ad_id, image_name, disabled, isprimary)
            (%d, %s, %d,%d)",
            $ad_id,
            $ad_img,
            0,
            0));
```

Also, disabled and `is_primary` should be Boolean. But I am not sure what the data type in here.

I also tried

```
$wpdb->insert(
'{$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos', // Table name
array(
    'ad_id' => $ad_id,
    'image_name' => $ad_img,
    'disabled' => 0,
    'is_primary' => 0,
), // Columns
array(
    '%s',
    '%d',
    '%d',
    '%d'
) // Explicit formatting
```

);

But haven't got any luck yet.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Can you explain *what* doesn't work? What errors are thrown? What is it doing, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error.

Comment: I also tried to echo $ad_id and $ad_img, all of them are valid value

Comment: are you sure with the prefix , itsnt like that `{$wpdb->prefix}_awpcp_adphotos`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be (?) :

```
$wpdb->query(
     $wpdb->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos(`ad_id`, `image_name`, `disabled`, `isprimary`) 
            VALUES(%d, %s, %d,%d)",
            $ad_id, $ad_img, 0, 0)
 );
```

I think you wrote the entire thing wrong, maybe by mistake :)

For your edit, if using `insert()` should be like:

```
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'awpcp_adphotos', array(
     'ad_id' => $ad_id,
     'image_name' => $image_name,
     'disabled' => $disabled,
     'isprimary' => $isprimary,
));
```